# New oven/range wiring

Tags: electrical, oven

Afternoon,

We currently have a gas range cook top with electric oven underneath that is hooked up to a 40 amp breaker via 8/3 romex wire. We are replacing this with an all gas range/oven that only requires 120 volts/15 amp breaker. My question is can I use the existing 8/3 wire by splicing 12/2 via one junction box at the service panel end and another box in an accessible spot just before the new oven, capping off the red wire at both ends? I'd then replace the 40 amp breaker with a 15 amp and connect 12/2, then connect the other spliced 12/2 into a new receptacle for the oven.

My original plan was just to attach fishing wire to the existing 8/3, pull out the 8/3 from the service panel, then attach 12/2 to the fishing wire and fish that through to the service panel. I will go this route if I have to but it involves several cuts into drywall, undoing bulkheads and acoustic tiles, etc.

Comment: See https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/150236/converting-8-3-220vac-oven-recptacle-to-120v-recptacle?rq=1

Answer (score 3):

Yes, that is acceptable. You don't need a junction box at the service panel end. You can have a pigtail in the service panel. You also don't need another box for the oven. Just remove the existing receptacle, pigtail on some 12 gauge wire, and put in a standard outlet.

Keeping the 8/3 in place also allows for future replacement with an electric oven by swapping out the receptacle.

Comment: OK - I was just concerned about having space for a pigtail in the new receptacle box, going from 8 gauge to 12 gauge.

Comment: If it's a tiny single-gang box, you're probably right. But if it was done right with a double-gang box, you should be fine.

Comment: You don't even need a pigtail in the service panel if the new breaker can take #8.  Many can.

Comment: I just saw this online: https://www.reliableparts.ca/product/Gas-Range-Power-Adapter-1515526/475472

Seems too good to be true. Does this just plug into the 220 receptacle that my current oven is using, and I would plug the new oven into the adapter? Would I still need to change the breaker?

Comment: Longnecks answer is probably the best way to do it. Don't use a cheater cord your devices won't be properly protected. Your new outlet will be smaller than the existing outlet so you should be fine pigtailing in the box.+

Comment: So one thing I did not mention is there is not an existing box in the wall. The 8/3 wire connects to a huge external female receptacle. The oven then plugs into that. So I'd just have to put in a big enough new work box, run the existing 8/3 into that, pigtail to 12/2 and then hook up my new 110 receptacle.

Comment: Why new work? You probably want an old work box. But your plan sounds OK.

Comment: Sorry, confused myself.

One more thing - I'm assuming now the oven will require 20 amp service. If it so happens it needs 15 amps, will my plan still work with 14/2 wire?